# Автоматическая синхронизация папок Windows 10 и Fedora

Tags: linux, администрирование, windows-10, dual-boot, fedora

Обе системы установлены на одной машине и загружаются поочерёдно, необходимо чтобы обе системы при старте либо периодически синхронизировали содерживомое двух папок в двух системах.
В общем надо, чтобы папки с документами в обеих системах всегда были идентичны по содержанию.

Comment: Сделать общий раздел жёсткого диска, не?

Comment: предполагается синхронизация стандартных папок с документами

Comment: Переделать стандартные папки в ссылки на общий раздел жёсткого диска?) В обоих ОС это вроде бы возможно

Comment: имейте ввиду, что драйвер файловой системы ntfs3g позволяет создавать в ntfs файлы в нижнем и верхнем регистре, то есть в linux File.txt и file.txt будут разные файлы, что в Windows является недопустимым